# Animate element without animating pseudo-elements

Tags: css, css-animations, pseudo-element

I have a div and both ::before and ::after pseudo-elements of this div.
I want to animate each one of them with different delays(0, 0.5s and 1.0).

I have tried in many ways until I realized I could move both **pseudo-elements** with the delay I wanted, but not the **div** itself or I could move only the **div** and the **pseudo-elements** would move in the same timing.

In the second case, if I try to animate the **pseudo-elements** separately, they do the animation twice.

**First example:**

```
.wave {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 26px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 26px;
}

.wave:before, .wave:after {
  animation: bounce 1s linear infinite alternate;
  border-radius: inherit;
  content: ' ';
  height: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
}

.wave:before {
  background-color: red;
  right: 30px;
}

.wave:after {
  background-color: green;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  left: 30px;
}
```

**Seconde example:**

```
.wave {
  animation: bounce 1s linear infinite alternate;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 26px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 26px;
}

.wave:before, .wave:after {
  border-radius: inherit;
  content: ' ';
  height: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
}

.wave:before {
  background-color: red;
 right: 30px;
}

.wave:after {
  background-color: green;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
  left: 30px;
}
```

Having said that, all I want to know is:

Is it possible to move all of them, using only one div, with different timing? How so?

**EDIT 1**

Here is a codepen, highlighting this case:
https://codepen.io/haaswill/pen/vyroJG

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just put the animation property on the :before and :after

I fiddled with this heh - I was able to get the 3 parts to animate on their own. Check it out here:
https://jsfiddle.net/karolbrennan/706gkbna/2/

```
@keyframes bounce {
    0%   {left: 0px; }
    25%  {left: 25px; }
    50%  {left: 50px; }
    75%  {left: 25px; }
    100% {left: 0px; }
}

.wave {
  animation: bounce 3.5s linear infinite alternate;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 26px;
}

.wave:before, .wave:after {
  background-color: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  content: ' ';
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
}

.wave:before {
  animation: bounce 1.5s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
  right: 30px;
}

.wave:after {
  animation: bounce 2s linear infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  left: 30px;
}
```

There's an article about this here: https://cssanimation.rocks/pseudo-elements/

Comment: I have already read this article, but, when I put animation properties, like delay or the whole animation property, it works as if there were two animations. Actually it animates the div, which moves both pseudo-elements by itself and more the animations from ::before and ::after, consequently, the pseudo-elements move two times the initial position.

Comment: Could you put this into a fiddle? Would be easier to diagnose :)

Comment: Now I saw your fiddle, I didn't see it on mobile. And it actually displays what is happening in my case. If you change the color of each element, you can visualize that they move for different distances. Like I said, ::before and ::after animate twice. PS: I edited my question with the pen I am trying to develop.